# Double X-screens on one monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xserver

I have two monitors connected currently, my laptop display and an old Dell monitor. For some reason one monitor (the Dell) has double everything (it will make sense when you see the image).

I think it came about when one day I tried using separate x-screen instead of just twin view for a specific reason I don't remember why (I was trying to get the Menu bar to show on my laptop monitor instead of the Dell I believe, it only shows up on the left-most monitor it seems) but anyhow I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this issue.

Please let me know if any additional information is required in order to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only using displays in System Settings? Otherwise, I'm not surprised it's the Dell one that's having trouble.

Comment: it doesnt recognize the dell but today I booted my computer and logged in, (it's only on this user account on my computer btw) it now has triple instead of double on my laptop screen, I did not connect the dell this time???

Comment: I have no idea what's going on... save your files and applications to an external, and do a fresh install is my only advice.

Comment: Wait, have you tried without the Gnome shell?